# How to grab element with changing id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a script and I need to grab an element on a webpage.
I inspect the page and select the element with the help of chrome, I copy the css code of that element and the result is:

```
<a id="4edd60cf-0462-4b8b-9b60-1d41911f3309" href="javascript:void(0);">Join now.</a>
```

The problem is when I clear all the cache& cookies, the id of the element changes.

Are there any other methods to grab that?

I've tried to use the chrome's "copy selector" function but it doesn't work

Comment: We'd need the context. You can select by element `<a>` but I wouldn't expect that to be specific enough. You'd likely need to find an element with a unique class or ID, and traverse upwards or downwards to get to this element. Something along the lines of *"An `<a>` element that's the child of an element with `id="container"`"*, as an example.

Comment: Are there any parent elements of that element? You could try to find a direct parent that has a more static id and use that to grab the nearest anchor tag you need

Answer (score 1):

if you have no attribute to use, you can use  the text of the element.

```js
const link = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].find(e => e.text === 'Join now.')

if(link)
  link.style.color = 'green' // do something with the found link.
```

```html
<a id="4edd60cf-0462-4b8b-9b60-1d41911f3309" href="javascript:void(0);">Join now.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy enough to fetch the element using the text content, you can do so using xPath.  Here's a basic JavaScript example with a button to demonstrate...

```js
   // xPath of element you want to find
    var xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Join now')]";
    var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    
// Button code for demonstration purposes
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function () {   
alert(matchingElement.id); };
```

```html
   <a id="not-this" href="javascript:void(0);">Don't join.</a>
   <a id="4edd60cf-0462-4b8b-9b60-1d41911f3309" href="javascript:void(0);">Join now.</a>
    <a id="not-this" href="javascript:void(0);">Now join.</a>
    <br><br>
    <button id="test">Get the ID</button>
```